# How to increase the padding in the code snippet box when using `listings`?

Tags: listings

So I am writing a book on Awk programming language, and I have enabled a single frame via `\lstset{frame=single}`. However, I would like the code within the snippet box to be further away from the frame border. Any ideas how to change the padding of the code within the snippet box? In HTML I'd just do `padding: 5px`, but I can't figure out how to do it in LaTeX.

Comment: If you've found the solution, you can post and accept an answer to this question.