# listings: How to increase space between backgroundcolor-box and code?

Tags: listings

As you can see, the colored box created by `backgroundcolor` is quite tight. How can one increase the "padding", i.e., the space between the box and its content?

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16984/how-to-increase-the-padding-in-the-code-snippet-box-when-using-listings) seems to be related, but I don't have a frame around the color box, and the suggestions there did not solve the problem.

The package `framed` can put in shaded boxes (see the comments below), so one possibility would be to redefine `lstlisting`. Has anyone done that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\xdefinecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}
\lstset{% setup listings
    language=R,% set programming language
        backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}% background color
}

\begin{document}
\noindent Just some text.
%\begin{shaded*}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A first example}, label=list:ex]
x <- c(1, 3, 2)
id <- function(x){
    x # just a dummy
}
3 <= 4
3 != 4
!TRUE
y <- "foo"
(pv <- sum(x * x^x))
y ~ x + a
\end{lstlisting}
%\end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `framexleftmargin=<len>` to adjust the left margin. To adjust the top and bottom, there are similar options, but seem that you also need to specify `frame=tb`, to get the additional padding added on the top and bottom.  Including `framerule=0pt` will remove the rule if that is not desired.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\xdefinecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}
\lstset{% setup listings
    language=R,% set programming language
        backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},% background color
        framexleftmargin=16pt,
        framextopmargin=6pt,
        framexbottommargin=6pt, 
        frame=tb, framerule=0pt,
}

\begin{document}
\noindent Just some text.
%\begin{shaded*}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A first example}, label=list:ex]
x <- c(1, 3, 2)
id <- function(x){
    x # just a dummy
}
3 <= 4
3 != 4
!TRUE
y <- "foo"
(pv <- sum(x * x^x))
y ~ x + a
\end{lstlisting}
%\end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot, Peter. Actually, I just used `frame=ltb` (which already gives more space on the left side as well) with `framerule=0pt` and further increased the space on the left side with `framexleftmargin=1pt`. That's already good-looking.